# È corretto, in questa frase, l’uso del congiuntivo?

Tags: grammar, tenses

‎Nella seguente espressione, presa da Notizie.it, non capisco perché si usa il congiuntivo (siccome con "se" + indicativo nella proposizione subordinata, si usa anche l'indicativo nella proposizione principale):

> Se gli USA hanno delle prove, le condividano.

Comment: Perché la frase è un'esortazione, e perché il condividere le prove non sta succedendo, è un'ipotesi, quindi il modo indicativo sarebbe sbagliato.

Comment: Un appunto: è la proposizione introdotta da “se” la subordinata, mentre l'altra è la principale.

Comment: Si tratta di un [imperativo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperativo_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/).

Comment: Mi sono presa la libertà di modificare leggermente il contenuto di quello che hai scritto tra parentesi d'accordo con ciò che ha detto @DaG nel suo commento (non so cosa ho fatto, ma non posso votare quel commento).

Comment: @Charo, certo 
sarebbe un'opportunità per  imparare qualcosa da te.

Comment: @Charo Non si tratta di congiuntivo, ma di imperativo...

Comment: @Nico: nel mio commento c'è scritto "imperativo".

Comment: @Nico Se vuoi una risposta alla tua domanda, chiedilo su meta. Cancello i commenti anche qui perché irrilevanti alla domanda.

Comment: [Ho rimosso un mio commento non pertinente perché avevo letto male la domanda e credevo che si riferisse al modo verbale usato nella protasi.]

Comment: A proposito, @user11731289, il mio nome è Charo, non "chiaro" (non è un nome italiano). Nessun problema, solo che quando mi fai un ping con "chiaro" non mi arrivano le notifiche :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nella frase ci sono due verbi con lo stesso soggetto. Rivoltiamola con il soggetto nella principale:

> Gli USA condividano le prove, se le hanno

Nella subordinata è corretto l'indicativo, perché equivale a “se è vero che le hanno”. Il congiuntivo sarebbe errato.

Nella principale il congiuntivo è necessario:

> Gli USA condividono le prove, se le hanno

vorrebbe dire una cosa completamente diversa.

Il modo verbale della principale non è necessariamente indicativo. Può essere imperativo

> Va', se hai il coraggio

oppure condizionale

> Andrei, se il tempo è bello

oppure congiuntivo

> Faccia pure, se questo è il suo desiderio

Questo congiuntivo si chiama *esortativo*. La frase equivale a

> USA (vocativo), condividete (imperativo) le prove, se le avete

Comment: So che è un libro da far bruciare nella prossima festa di San Giovanni, ma su *Nuovo Contatto C1. Corso di lingua e civiltà italiana per stranieri* si spiega che nel cosiddetto "periodo ipotetico della realtà", la proposizione subordinata (quella introdotta da "se") si costruisce con un verbo all'indicativo, mentre il verbo della proposizione principale può essere all'indicativo, al condizionale semplice o all'imperativo. Fa questo esempio di questo ultimo caso: "Se viene Ada, fammelo sapere!". Come ha spiegato egreg in questa risposta, la frase della domanda rientra anche in questo caso.

Comment: Infatti, i casi di "congiuntivo" (congiuntivo esortativo) corrispondono a  [imperativi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperativo_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)   
di terza persona singolare o plurale o di prima persona plurale.

Comment: @egreg, Grazie per la tua rsiposta.

Answer (score 0):

Come scrive @linuxfan says Reinstate Monica, in "le condividano" si tratta di un'esortazione, vale a dire di un imperativo (coincidente morfologicamente con il congiuntivo), che è chiaramente compatibile con costruzioni ipotetiche ("se lo sai, dillo"), ma che non deve necessariamente apparire in tali costruzioni.
L'aspetto interessante è il carattere particolare di questo tipo di imperativo. L'enunciatore non esorta l'interlocutore, ma terzi di solito assenti.
L'uso libero di questa forma appare in frasi del tipo:
a) Mario vuole raccontarmi tutto.
b) Che lo faccia allora!

In questo caso l'imperativo indiretto richiede di solito l'enfasi di un "che" e/o di un "allora". L'uso del "che" potrebbe far pensare a una subordinata, ma rispecchia il fenomeno che Nicholas Evans denomina "insubordination" https://benjamins.com/catalog/tsl.115,
vale a dire una frase che pare una subordinata, ma che in realtà ricopre la funzione di una principale.

Comment: In questo caso si vede chiaramente come funziona questo sito. Scrivo una risposta praticamente in contemporanea a @egreg e con contenuto simile. Lui riceve 2 upvotes e io un downvote (chiaramente non spiegato). Questo rispecchia in modo esemplare la "professionalità" di chi opera in modo anonimo e lo fa solo per scoraggiare per contribuisce invece di esporsi a un dialogo.

Comment: @user11731289 Con molto piacere. In fin dei conti è importante il feedback di chi chiede.